# override and sum price with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm struggling with this code, I've two js that dynamically change the price of a div with id=#prezzo.

My problem is that I have a basic price of 1000 and I want that price to be overridden when I click on one of the three buttons (and not be overridden when I click on checkboxes).

```js
var basicPrice = 1000; // This is how we start
function getCheck() {
  var currentPrice = basicPrice; // every time
  currentPrice += parseFloat($(".event-hook-class.active").data("prezzo")) || 0, // add any "active" boxes
    services = [],
    total = 0;
    console.log(currentPrice)
  $("input[id^=service]").each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      total += +this.value;
      services.push($("[for=" +this.id + "]").html()); // get the label text
    }
  });
  $("#prezzo").text((currentPrice + total).toFixed(2) + "€");
  $("#serv").html("services: " + services.join(", "));
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[id^=service]").on("click", getCheck);
  $(".event-hook-class").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".event-hook-class").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active")
    $("#prezzo").html($(this).data('prezzo') + ' €');
    $("#mq").html($(this).data('mq'));
    getCheck(); // will add this and the checkboxes
  });
  getCheck(); // initialise on page load
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="event-hook-class simple-text piano" id="C.1_1" data-prezzo="1080.56" data-mq="94">
                              C.1_1 <br> piano 1<br> prezzo 1080.56 €</button><br><button type="button" class="event-hook-class simple-text piano" id="D.1_1" data-prezzo="1084.72" data-mq="94">
                              D.1_1 <br> piano 1<br> prezzo 1084.72 €</button><br><button type="button" class="event-hook-class simple-text piano" id="C_2.1" data-prezzo="1109.68" data-mq="94">
                              C_2.1 <br> piano 2<br> prezzo 1109.68 €</button><br>

<form id="services" name="services-form" data-name="services Form">
  <div class="checkbox-field w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="22500" id="service_1" name="checkbox" data-name="Checkbox" class="checkbox 1 w-checkbox-input"><label for="service_1" class="simple-text white w-form-label">design pack</label> 22500 €</div>
  <div class="checkbox-field ew w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="2000 " id="service_2" name="checkbox-2" data-name="service_2" class="checkbox 2 w-checkbox-input"><label for="service_2" class="simple-text white w-form-label">security</label> 2000 €</div>
  <div class="checkbox-field 2 w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="5000" id="service_3" name="checkbox-2" data-name="service_3" class="checkbox 3 w-checkbox-input"><label for="service_3" class="simple-text white w-form-label">wellness pack</label> 5000 €</div>
  <div class="checkbox-field 4 w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="1000" id="service_4" name="checkbox-2" data-name="service_4" class="checkbox 4 w-checkbox-input"><label for="service_4" class="simple-text white w-form-label">box auto</label> 1000 €</div>
</form>

<div class="paragraph" id="prezzo">
  1000 €</div>
<div id="display_services" class="simple-text maiusc prova">services:<br>design pack<br>dynamically adding the services...</div>
```

I'm new to js world, so I don't know how to do it:

Comment: you can comment this line to avoid  anything happening on click of checkboxes . $("input[id^=service]").on("click", getCheck);

Comment: hi @ManojYadav .  No no, I want that the price in the div change both in click on the checkboxes and on click of the buttons, but when I click on the buttons i need to override the basic price of 1000.. now, for example when I click on the first button it sums and 1000+1080.56.. but i don't want that sum for the button. i want only display the price of the buttons and override the 1000... for the checkboxes instead, they are fine like this..

Comment: Maybe change current price calc to not sum with basic price? `currentPrice = parseFloat($(".event-hook-class.active").data("prezzo")) || basicPrice`

Comment: it was that simple! thank you @Pagotti
i have another question.. is it possible to have direct help from you maybe through email? no free work obviously ;)

Comment: @StefanoZanetti I have limited free time and I use it to help people here and in SOpt (portuguese version of stack overflow). But if you have some project that I can help in my free time, send me at gmail (my box name is same as here) and I will glad to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change current price variable to choose between active button price and basic price in `getCheck` function:

```
var basicPrice = 1000; // This is how we start
function getCheck() {
  var currentPrice = parseFloat($(".event-hook-class.active").data("prezzo")) || basicPrice, // add any "active" boxes
    services = [],
    total = 0;
  console.log(currentPrice);
  $("input[id^=service]").each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      total += +this.value;
      services.push($("[for=" +this.id + "]").html()); // get the label text
    }
  });
  $("#prezzo").text((currentPrice + total).toFixed(2) + "€");
  $("#serv").html("services: " + services.join(", "));
}
```